# Need to fix the issue while accessing battery percent in defined function

Tags: python-3.x, function

if i use following code, i can access easily battery.percent

```
from psutil import sensors_battery
battery = sensors_battery()
print('Current Battery : ' + battery.percent + '% charge')
```

I'm confused to access battery.percent by defining a function.

```
from psutil import sensors_battery
from datetime import datetime

def tab():
    battery = sensors_battery()
    now = datetime.now()
    return battery, now

print('Current Battery : ' + battery.percent + '% charge')
pluggin_disc = time(now.hour, now.minute)
battery_disc = battery.percent

print('Your battery have ' + str(battery_disc) + '% \n Current Time is : ', pluggin_disc, '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your function. Otherwise python doesn't know what you mean by `battery.percent`.

E.g.

```
def tab():
    battery = sensors_battery()
    now = datetime.now()
    return battery, now

battery, now = tab()
print(... battery.percent ...)
```